# PHP generate PNG with dynamic date

Tags: php, date, datetime, dynamic

I'm looking to generate a .png image with a  dynamic date, ex:

take today's date +7 days and create a .png that displays that date.

I'd like to keep the .png name the same and just overwrite once a week, always showing the date + 7 from that one day a week.

```
site.com/img/date.png
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the GNU `date` command, you can get the date 7 days from now with:

```
date -d '+7 days'
```

You could then pump that, or whatever parts of it you want into the script in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875472/2836621).

You don't say how you want it formatted, but that script comes up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick can do this fairly easily and is easy to have it run as a cronjob for automatic generation.